# Material design date picker z index issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

My problem is, that not the whole datepicker is shown, instead, I would have to scroll down in my modal if, for example, I want to enter the 18th of a month [as shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTwrv.png)

So I need to get the datepicker in front of the modal box.

Here is the JSFiddle link for reference. 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jimishf/sm98aycs/)

And my Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
  $('#bdate').pickadate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Submit your Informations</a>

<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Add Your Details</h4>
    <label for="bdate">Your birthdate</label>
    <input type="date" id="bdate" class="datepicker" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share code in your question and describe about your problem...

Comment: Please check above jsfiddle link. In that link u can see code and datepicker issue.

Comment: What you have tried so far @muralim

Comment: I tried to get datepicker on modal box.

Comment: In jsfiddle datepicker is displaying

Comment: Yes. But it is not displaying fully. Its showing inside of modal box with scroll function. But i need to display datepicker fully without scroll function.

Comment: Try by increasing height of your modal box

Comment: If i increase height of my modal box it will work. But I have only one date field. My datepicker height is above 400px. If I apply this height it is not look good. I hope now you understand my situation.

Comment: Try this css to decrease datepicker height `.picker__date-display {
  display:none;
}`

Comment: It is changed my datepicker design. But this is also good solution for this issue. Thanks lot @Vinothini

Answer (score 0):

There was a [github issue](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1032) about this problem with some solutions.
`pickadate` has this option `container`:

```
$('#bdate').pickadate({
    container: 'body'
})
```

Check [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sm98aycs/32/)